# KDB, console remembers old version of script

Tags: kdb

I am observing an odd behaviour. My Q console remembers the old version for a very simlpe q. script. I keep modifying .q script and rerunning, no help. Is there "cache" in q.exe? if yes, can something be reset?

windows version -> KDB+ 3.2 2014.

Comment: Can you give an example like what's in the script, where do you save it, where your q resides, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't paste the script but I can describe it.
1. It had a remote connection handle to another KDB instance.
2. It had a function call which called executed "select..."

Answer (score 1):

the q.exe doesn't remember anything at all. That's entirely OS-related (e.g. command history).

**EDIT after comments**

q behaves just like any other scripting language: when you load it, it will do what the script says but will not change its behaviour if you change the file **without reloading**. To do this either restart the q instance or explicitly load it in the current one:

```
\l /path/to/file.q
```

Comment: I know how many question sounded. And yet, I stand by my words. Q was somehow "remembering" old version of the script. Once, I bounced q, it cleared the problem. I run 64 bit version.

Comment: I think I see what you mean here, you load the script in a Q session, change the script and save it without reloading the Q session again. Then yes, once a script is loaded into a Q session, everything in script in defined in memory. Changing the script without reloading the script in the Q session won't refresh any function you have changed in the script. Try `\l path/to/script` once you modified your script to reload the script.

Comment: Yes, it's just like running any other type of script - run scripts for python, sql, perl etc - their behaviour won't change when you change the file. It would have to be loaded again. "keep modifying .q script and rerunning" -- somewhat misleading :-) How were you re-running if not restarting q?